# Nginx config failed

Tags: linux, nginx

Can someone help me with this error I have.

```
(40: Too many levels of symbolic links) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:60
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I make

1- `nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/plex.conf`

2- `sudo nginx -t`

3 - this error popup

thanks for help

Comment: The error message refers to line 60 in a specific file. Have you looked at that line and tried to follow what's going on?

Comment: Please post line 60 of your configuration.

Comment: ##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}